# Is there a mass use for rubber or sticky resin?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-technic-pack, minecraft-industrialcraft

I have a system that automatically produces rubber from my river bees. I need the clay dust to make iridium so the rubber is a byproduct but I was wondering if there is any mass use for rubber?

I currently have an iron chest that's nearly full of rubber and I have no use for it.

Also if there is any use for sticky resin because I make the rubber from the wet propolis so I convert that to normal propolis. Than that makes the resin which makes the rubber.

I would love to use the rubber but if there is no mass use, I would also like to know a use for sticky resin.

Comment: Could you state the pack/mod list so we can identify what you can work with?

Comment: @DarkDestry I play on ftb mindcrack, ftb ultimate and tekkit. My rubber farm is on mindcrack but if there is a good use for the rubber i'm planing to make it also on my other worlds

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using one of the technic packs I have played (there are like 4 now I think lol) making a HV solar array takes something like 3000-4000 rubber each, they are a great power source.

Comment: How is it made? Can you show what ot looks like so i can check if it exists in my pack?

Comment: check both existence and how to craft using NEI?

Comment: It takes a ton of resources because you build solar pannels then combine 8 into low voltage arrays, 8 of those into medium voltage arrays then 8 of those into a HV array. It looks like a regular size block which is white-grey on the sides and a light blue on the top. It is definitely in Tekkit lite and Tekkit classic but I forget exactly which base mod it is a part of, pretty sure it's the same one that ads generators and the machines like macerator compressor and electric furnace.